# Equivalent to Octave pinv() in PHP?

Tags: php, matrix, octave

I'm taking [this amazing course](https://class.coursera.org/ml-007) from Andrew Ng on Coursera about Machine Learning and I want to implement some of the things we learn in my "native language" to make sure I'm understanding all the course material. I found [this Matrix class](https://github.com/carbocation/CarbocationStatisticsBundle/blob/master/Regression/Matrix.php) written by Shankar Manamalkav (2011) and with a few adjustment I managed to get pretty much all matrix functions I needed, except one: the equivalent to pinv() from Octave. Although I'm not sure what pinv() does (analytically), it essentially stands for pseudo-inverse of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help (I dont know Octave), but look at this:

[Lapack::pseudoInverse — Calculate the inverse of a matrix](http://php.net/manual/en/lapack.pseudoinverse.php)

Good luck

Comment: It looks available only to Linux

Answer (score 0):

`pinv()` calculates the pseudo inverse of a matrix. To PHP, a matrix is an array. PHP has an optional class called Lapack that gives you that functionality. You have to install it. You can learn more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/lapack.setup.php), including how to install it.

Here is some example code:

```
<?php
 $a = array(
       array( 8, 1, 6 ),
       array( 3, 5, 7 ),
       array( 4, 9, 2 ),
   );

   $result = Lapack::pseudoInverse($a);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: How do I install that on Windows? It looks available only to Unix system.

Comment: Windows support is currently not included - once the API is stabilized though this will be added relatively shortly. (https://github.com/ianbarber/php-lapack)